# Using 'wsh.Run' in VBA with spaces in filepath

Tags: excel, vba, escaping, filepath

I am having trouble with using the WSH.run command and escaping the spaces in the filepath - it works fine without spaces! I have tried using double, triple and quadruple quotation marks around each parameter/filepath but it does not like the filepath when the cmd shell is called from the VBA script. This is the script without any escaping:

```
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim xslFilePath As String
Dim RetVal

Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

firstFilePath = "C:\Program Files\myprogram.exe"
secondFilePath = "C:\Program Files\stylesheet.xsl"

strfilepath = "D:\outputfiles\out.xls"
outpath = Mid(strFilePath, InStrRev(strFilePath, "\") + 1)
outfile = Left(strFilePath, InStrRev(strFilePath, ".") - 1)
logfile = outfile & "_errors.log"

cmd1 = firstFilePath & " -s:" & strFilePath & " -xsl:" & secondFilePath & " -o:" & outfile & ".csv > " & logfile & " 2>&1"

wsh.Run "cmd /c /s" & cmd1, 2, True
```

When I run the following via the command-line with the escaped filepaths the command completes successfully, so I am not sure why this is not working in Excel when it is called with the same escaping applied?

```
"C:\Program Files\myprogram.exe" -s:"D:\outputfiles\out.xls" -xsl:"C:\Program Files\stylesheet.xsl" -o:"D:\outputfiles\out.csv" > "D:\outputfiles\out_errors.log" 2>&1
```

Any advice or help appreciated.

Comment: Double the quotes. `""` in the string literal when you want `"` in the string path.

Comment: thanks, I have tried that too but doesn't seem to work when adding double quotes around the `firstFilePath` and `secondFilePath` strings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for your `cmd1` line

```
cmd1 = """""" & firstFilePath & """ -s:""" & strFilePath & """ -xsl:""" & secondFilePath & """ -o:""" & outfile & ".csv"" > """ & logfile & """ 2>&1"""
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work for me, that doesn't write out the log file either for some reason.

Comment: You may have to wrap the whole command in quote marks as well - try with my update (just edited)

Comment: dude, that's awesome and working like a treat now :) thanks so much for quick reply.